# Why is the group operation $A\cdot \{v_1,...,v_n\}:=\{Av_1,...,Av_n\}$ transitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

1. $\mathcal{O}=\{\{v_1,...,v_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n \mid\{v_1,...,v_n\} \text{ is  an orthonormal Basis of } \mathbb{R}^n\}$
2. $\mathcal{S}^{n-1}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \| x\|=1\}$

I have to prove that $\operatorname{O}(n)\times \mathcal{O}\to \mathcal{O}, (A,\{v_1,...,v_n\})\mapsto A\boldsymbol{\cdot} \{v_1,...,v_n\}=\{Av_1,...,Av_n\}$ is a transitive group operation, hence for two elements $\{a_1,...,a_n\},\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ there has to be a $A\in \operatorname{O}(n)$ such that $A\{a_1,...,a_n\}=\{Aa_1,...,Aa_n\}=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$

I don't really know what to prove here. Since $A$ is orthogonal matrix, we know that $|\det(A)|=1\neq 0$ and thus there will be an inverse $A^{-1}$. Isn't this basically a system of equations $Aa_1=b_1,...,Aa_n=b_n$?

Comment: How do you change basis in general?

Comment: I try to express the basis vectors with the basis vectors of the other base

Comment: Indeed, place those coefficients on a matrix. Show that matrix is in $O(n).$

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You want to show for any two orthonormal bases $\{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$ and
$\{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$ there is an orthogonal matrix going from one basis to the other.
That is, $A a_k = b_k$ for each $k$.

Of course, since the $\{ a_k \}$ form a basis, *you've now defined a map on a basis*. So this extends to a linear map in a unique way. Do you know how to find the matrix associated to a linear map? Once you have this matrix in hand, can you show it's orgthogonal? This will amount to checking that each $b_i \cdot b_j = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}$ (do you see why?), which will be true because of the orthonormal-ness of the $\{ b_k \}$ basis.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: If it's helpful, you might even assume that $\{a_k\}$ is the standard basis. After all, group actions are invertible, so if you show the standard basis can get anywhere, then you get full transitivity by going from $\{ a_k \}$ to the standard basis, then from the standard basis to $\{ b_k \}$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it :)